# Graphs derived from colorings of locally finite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let us assume we are in the following situation:
We have a connected regular locally finite graph $G=(V,E)$ and let us call the degree of an arbitrary (and therefore any) vertex $d$.

In addition we are given a coloring of the vertices with finitely many colors $c:V\rightarrow \{1,...,n\}$ with the property that for any vertex $v$ the multiset of colors of its neighbors (i.e. $\{c(x)~|~x \in V, \{x,v\} \in E \}$ as a multiset) only depends on its color $c(v)$ and not on the vertex itself.

Let us now consider the graph $G_1=(V_1,E_1)$ which we derive from $G$ as follows:
$V_1=\{v \in V~|~ c(v)=1\}$ and $E_1$ consists of all pairs $\{v,v'\}$ such that there is **no** $v'' \in V_1$ such that $\mathrm{dist}_G(v,v')=\mathrm{dist}_G(v,v'')+\mathrm{dist}_G(v'',v')$.

I.e. $v$ and $v'$ are connected in $G_1$ if and only if there is no minimal length path in $G$ connecting $v$ and $v'$ such that one of the vertices along the way already has color $1$.

Then $G_1$ is a well-defined graph and I would like to know whether $G_1$ is again locally finite.

**Edit:** Ok, after thinking about it, the answer in general is no.

As a counterexample consider a $4$-regular tree colored with two colors such that each vertex has two neighbors of each color.

Thus I would like to rephrase the question as:

> Under what conditions can I guarantee that the resulting graph is again locally finite? E.g. does it help if we assume that $G$ is not a tree and that the automorphism group of $G$ acts transitively on the vertices of each color?